# Java Recursive Decimal to Binary Function Printing Backwards

Tags: java, recursion, binary, decimal, data-conversion

I am coding a Lab exercise for one of my classes. The question asks to "Write a recursive function convert a decimal number into a binary number, printing the binary number" 
Using the constructor `public static void decToBin(int num){}`

Current code:

```
public class convert {
    public static void decToBin(int num) {
        if (num > 0) {
            decToBin(num /= 2);
            System.out.print(num % 2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        decToBin(50);
    }
}
```

Output:
`011001`

Unfortunately, when the program unpacks all the methods that were called and ends them it prints out my number in binary but backwards.
I have tried just about everything under the sun and nothing works for me.

If anybody could tell me where the problem lies, give me a hint or anything.
I just need a second opinion on this code.
Thank you!

Comment: Not related, but wouldn't it print the wrong value for 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dividing by 2 before you print out your answer which is messing with the result. The corrected function would be.

```
public static void decToBin(int num) {
    if (num > 0) {
        decToBin(num / 2);
        System.out.print(num % 2);
    }
}
```

Then to reverse the order, you can flip the lines.

```
public static void decToBin(int num) {
    if (num > 0) {
        System.out.print(num % 2);
        decToBin(num / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin, it turns out the ' /= ' was the problem and all it needed was to be changed to ' / '

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to print `num % 2` before calling the function on `num /= 2`. and you need to **reverse** the output to get the binary number because when converting to binary you type the numbers from right to left.